# WHERE clause in nested query is not improving efficiency

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I am running a pretty query intensive RANK window function in MYSQL.

The query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    RANK () OVER (
        PARTITION BY 
            t1.`country`, 
            t1.`product_id`, 
            t1.`retrieveDate`, 
            t1.`retrieveHour` 
        ORDER BY 
            t1.`retrieveDatetime` DESC) AS `ranking`
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM product_data
    WHERE retrieveDate > (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
) t1
WHERE t1.ranking = 1
```

I originally set up a WHERE filter in the nested query to limit the amount of data to run the actual query but from running `EXPLAIN` I noticed that no matter what I set with the `retrieveDate` filter (`1 WEEK`, `1 MONTH`, `2 MONTH`), it does not improve performance whatsoever.

This is the `EXPLAIN` output:

```json
{
    "query_block": {
      "select_id": 1,
      "cost_info": {
        "query_cost": "355813.66"
      },
      "windowing": {
        "windows": [
          {
            "name": "<unnamed window>",
            "using_filesort": true,
            "filesort_key": [
              "`product_id`",
              "`country`",
              "`retrieveDate`",
              "`retrieveHour`",
              "`retrieveDatetime` desc"
            ],
            "functions": [
              "rank"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "cost_info": {
          "sort_cost": "271814.81"
        },
        "table": {
          "table_name": "product_data",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 815526,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 271814,
          "filtered": "33.33",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "2446.25",
            "eval_cost": "27181.48",
            "prefix_cost": "83998.85",
            "data_read_per_join": "553M"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "product_id",
            "country",
            "category",
            "rank",
            "primaryCategory",
            "primaryCategoryRank",
            "retrieveDatetime",
            "createdAt",
            "updatedAt",
            "retrieveDate",
            "retrieveHour"
          ],
          "attached_condition": "(`product_data`.`retrieveDate` > <cache>((curdate() - interval 1 week)))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Any thoughts on how to actually improve this query?
I currently have the following indexes set up:

```
BTree index
product_id, type=varchar, pos=1
country, type=int, pos=2
retrieveDate, type=date, pos=13
retrieveHour, type=int, pos=14
retrieveDatetime, type=datetime, pos=10
```

as well as one standalone retrieveDatetime index

Comment: How many rows does the subquery produce for 1 week, 1 month, 2 months ?

Comment: 1 week: 162,413
1 month: 496,432
2 month: 751,008

Comment: Have you tried calculating the date in your app and feeding the query with a constant value instead of the current expression? E.g. `WHERE retrieveDate > "2022-06-01"` ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, in the last line of your SQL `t1.ranking = 1` won't run, because `ranking` isn't a column in the table `product_data` (unless it coincidentally *is* at which point you've might've found your problem, lol). Assuming that's just a typo. I'm also going to assume that if you run:

```
SELECT * FROM product_data WHERE retrieveDate > (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

That it *is*  actually faster than `WHERE retrieveDate > (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`, yeah? If not, then it has nothing to do with your outer query. Can you try it without the subquery at all? I'm wondering whether MySQL is just choosing an bad optimisation strategy because of it.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    RANK () OVER (
        PARTITION BY 
            `country`, 
            `product_id`, 
            `retrieveDate`, 
            `retrieveHour` 
        ORDER BY 
            `retrieveDatetime` DESC) AS `ranking`
FROM product_data
WHERE retrieveDate > (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND ranking = 1;
```